# Android Fragment table display

Tags: android-fragments

I have an app in which I use fragments to display a dynamically generated table in the right pane.
This works if I comment out the code for the table so that ststic code in the layout file is displayed in the right pane, but when I include the table it inserts itself into the left hand panel  - it should be under the text in the right pane.
Extracts attached from layout file and code for inserting the table (cannot upload screen shots as new user).
I've tried numerous solutions and assume there is something wrong with the table code, either in the layout or in the Java.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="50dip"
  android:background="@color/background_color"
  >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/display_readings_title"
    style="@style/textstyle.Heading"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logout" 
    android:text="@string/display_readings_title" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/patient_id_text"
    style="@style/textstyle"
    android:text="@string/patient_id_text" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/display_readings_title"
    />

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/patient_id"
    style="@style/textstyle"
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/display_readings_title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/patient_id_text"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/patient_id_text"
        />

     <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/patient_name_text"
    style="@style/textstyle"
    android:text="@string/patient_name_text" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/patient_id_text"
    />

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/patient_name"
    style="@style/textstyle"
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/patient_id_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/patient_name_text"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/patient_name_text"
        />

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollPatientReadings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/patient_name_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"

    >   

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3" 
    android:id="@+id/patient_table"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    >
</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Extract from Java code

```
patient_table = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.patient_table);

        // get patient's readings from the database

                db.open();
                createTableTitle();
                Cursor c = db.getPatientReadings(idtext);
                extractValues(c);
                db.close();
            }

    // create title row

        private void createTableTitle() {
            TableRow titlerow;
            TextView tl1, tl2, tl3, tl4;
            titlerow = new TableRow(getActivity());
            titlerow.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 10);

            tl1 = new TextView(getActivity());
            tl1.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
            tl1.setTextSize(20);
            tl2 = new TextView(getActivity());
            tl2.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
            tl2.setTextSize(20);

            tl3 = new TextView(getActivity());
            tl3.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
            tl3.setTextSize(20);

            tl4 = new TextView(getActivity());
            tl4.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
            tl4.setTextSize(20);

            tl1.setText("INR");
            tl2.setText("Surface Bleeding");
            tl3.setText("Internal Bleeding");
            tl4.setText("Date");

            titlerow.addView(tl1);
            titlerow.addView(tl2);
            titlerow.addView(tl3);
            titlerow.addView(tl4);

            patient_table.addView(titlerow);

        }

        private void extractValues(Cursor c) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String inrReading = c.getString(2);
                    String surface_bleeds = c.getString(3);
                    String internal_bleeding = c.getString(4);
                    String currentDateTimeString = c.getString(5);

                    fillPatientTable(inrReading, surface_bleeds, internal_bleeding,
                            currentDateTimeString);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        // Display in table

        private void fillPatientTable(String inrReading, String surface_bleeds,
                String internal_bleeding, String currentDateTimeString) {

            TableRow row;
            TextView t1, t2, t3, t4;
            row = new TableRow(getActivity());
            row.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);

            t1 = new TextView(getActivity());
            t1.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
            t1.setTextSize(18);
            t2 = new TextView(getActivity());
            t2.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
            t2.setTextSize(18);
            t3 = new TextView(getActivity());
            t3.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
            t3.setTextSize(18);
            t4 = new TextView(getActivity());
            t4.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
            t4.setTextSize(18);

            t1.setText(inrReading);
            t2.setText(surface_bleeds);
            t3.setText(internal_bleeding);
            t4.setText(currentDateTimeString);

            row.addView(t1);
            row.addView(t2);
            row.addView(t3);
            row.addView(t4);

            patient_table.addView(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

After much searching and creating a parallel app I found that the problem was due to a stupid mistake. The view 'patient_table' into which the dynamic data was to be put, was also being referenced by another fragment which created a list to click on that triggered the table.